# Write prime numbers between 1 to 100 through VBA coding

Tags: vba, excel, primes

I found the below coding but its not working. Please share the more appropriate code for writing prime numbers in VBA

```
Private Sub cmdPrime_Click()
Dim p, n, i As Integer
p = 1
Print “Prime Numbers are : ”
For n = 1 To 100
For i = 2 To n – 1
If n Mod i = 0 Then
p = 0
Exit For
Else
p = 1
End If

Next
If p = 1 Then
Print n
End If

Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you were translating this from another language? You really should have pointed out which lines were failing and what you researched.

The `“”`: Smart quotes. This is typical of when copying between applications, so be careful. The speech marks for use in the visual basic editor need to be `""` in order to compile.

If you put `Option Explicit` at the top of your code it gives you lots of nice warnings about variable declarations and spellings by the way.

You are only going to 100 so `Integer` is fine, but there are no advantages of `Integer` over `Long` in this instance, so using `Long` is safer in case you decide, in the future, to go beyond the capacity of an `Integer`, and then you risk overflow. You would also, at a sufficiently high upper limit, need to factor out `mod`.

> The [MOD function](https://excel.tips.net/T003302_Large_Numbers_in_the_MOD_Function.html) returns an error if the divisor (the second argument
>   in the MOD function), multiplied by 134,217,728, is less than or equal
>   to the number being evaluated (the first argument in the MOD
>   function).

Microsoft suggest re-working as `=number-(INT(number/divisor)*divisor)`; which I guess you could replace `INT` with `CLng` in to keep with Longs.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub cmdPrime_Click()
    Dim p As Long, n As Long, i As Long, iCounter As Long
    p = 1
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(iCounter + 1, 1) = "Prime Numbers are: " 'Debug.Print "Prime Numbers are: "
        For n = 2 To 100 ''< As pointed out 1 is not technically a prime btw so can start at 2
            For i = 2 To n - 1
                If n Mod i = 0 Then              ' If n - (CLng(n / i) * i) = 0 Then
                    p = 0
                    Exit For
                Else
                    p = 1
                End If
            Next
            If p = 1 Then
                iCounter = iCounter + 1
                .Cells(iCounter, 1) = n  'Debug.Print n  
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

To preserve for future readers: The additional helpful comments are from @ChrisNeilsen.

To test if `n` is prime, you only need to test divisability up to square root of `n`. And you only need to test for divisibility by previously detected primes. And you can skip even values of `n`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. This code worked now. But what if I need the output in the excel spreadsheet rather than in the Immediate Window. Can you please provide the code for that?

Comment: @QHarr: Did you really mean for `p` and `n` to be `variant`?

Comment: @AJD I absolutely did not. Let me have a peek! Thank you.

Comment: Couple of points:  to test if n is prime, you only need to test disability up to square root of n.  And you only need to test for divisibility by previously detected primes.  And you can skip even values of n

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thanks. I have added your comments in. I have seen some nice implementations for project Euler and Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly more efficient version of the code. Two things modified:

a) Since 1 is [not considered prime](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/one.html), the outer loop starts from 2.

b) By default, the number is considered prime. If it is detected as a non-prime, further checks are stopped. *(In the posted code, the value p = 1 is set for each time a check detects a number as non-prime. Incrementing a counter each time p=1 is set shows that it is set 1059 times.)*

```
Option Explicit
Sub generatePrimes()
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim n, i As Integer
    For n = 2 To 100
       flag = True
        For i = 2 To n - 1
          If n Mod i = 0 Then
             flag = False
             Exit For
          End If
        Next
        If flag = True Then
          Debug.Print i
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Output:

```
 2 
 3 
 5 
 7 
 11 
 13 
 17 
 19 
 23 
 29 
 31 
 37 
 41 
 43 
 47 
 53 
 59 
 61 
 67 
 71 
 73 
 79 
 83 
 89 
 97
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. This code worked now. But what if I need the output in the excel spreadsheet rather than in the Immediate Window. Can you please provide the code for that?

Comment: You could add this to the line where `i` is being output. `Cells(row, column) = i`. Then do a `row = row + 1`. Initialize `row` and `column` before starting the loops.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question while brushing up my VBA skills. Here is my solution using [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm with `6k ± 1` optimization and ignoring all even and divisors of 5.

I have created 2 modules for separating logic and utility functions. Prints the 1st `100,000` prime numbers in `10 seconds` approx.

**Module 1 (PrimeNumber):**

```
Option Explicit

Sub PrintPrimes()

Dim count As Long
Dim s As Object
Dim primes As New ArrayList
Dim startTime As Date
Dim endTime As Date

startTime = Now

Set s = Sheet1.Cells
count = s(1, 2) - 1

Set primes = GetPrimeList(count)

PrintArray primes, "Sheet1", 2
endTime = Now

s(1, 3) = "Elapsed time: " & ElapsedTime(endTime, startTime)

End Sub

Function GetPrimeList(count) As ArrayList

Dim primeList As New ArrayList
Dim i As Long
Dim currentInt As Long

i = 2
primeList.Add (2)
currentInt = 3

Do While (primeList.count <= count)
    If IsPrime(currentInt) Then primeList.Add (currentInt)
    currentInt = currentInt + 2 'ignore even numbers
Loop

Set GetPrimeList = primeList

End Function

Function IsPrime(number)

Dim i As Long
Dim maxValidator As Long
Dim possiblePrime As Boolean

i = 3
IsPrime = True
possiblePrime = False
maxValidator = Round_Up(Sqr(number))

If number = 3 Then
    IsPrime = True
    Exit Function
ElseIf number Mod 5 = 0 And number > 5 Then
    IsPrime = False
    Exit Function
End If

If (number Mod 6 = 1 Or number Mod 6 = 5) Then possiblePrime = True

If possiblePrime Then
    Do While (i <= maxValidator)
        If number Mod i = 0 Then
            IsPrime = False
            Exit Do
        End If
        i = i + 2 'ignore even divisors
    Loop
Else
    IsPrime = False
End If

End Function
```

**Module 2 (Utils):**

```
Option Explicit

Function Round_Up(ByVal d As Double) As Long
    Dim result As Long
    result = Math.Round(d)
    If result >= d Then
        Round_Up = result
    Else
        Round_Up = result + 1
    End If
End Function

Function PrintArray(Data, SheetName As String, intStartRow As Integer)

    Dim oWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Set oWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)

    i = intStartRow
    For Each item In Data
        oWorksheet.Cells(i, 1) = item
        i = i + 1
    Next

End Function

Function ElapsedTime(endTime As Date, startTime As Date)
    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim Interval As Date

    ' Calculate the time interval.
    Interval = endTime - startTime

    ' Format and print the time interval in days, hours, minutes and seconds.
    strOutput = Int(CSng(Interval)) & " days " & Format(Interval, "hh") _
        & " Hours " & Format(Interval, "nn") & " Minutes " & _
        Format(Interval, "ss") & " Seconds"
    ElapsedTime = strOutput

End Function
```

Enter the number of prime numbers to be listed in the cell `B1`.

Press `Alt+F8` and then select `PrintPrimes` (should be selected by default) and then click on `Run`.

Voila! Prime numbers list will be printed from cell `A2`.
Cell `A1` is left blank for user input like **Enter the number of primes to be printed**.

**Note:**
I have used `Long` data type to cover more values instead of `Integer`. Incase if you need more values to be printed than `2,147,483,647`, then just replace `Long` to `Double` in `PrimeNumber` module. You will see a significant performance degradation in case of `Double` data type!

**PS:** Make sure to early bind *mscorlib.dll* using [this](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist/) link